# Understanding a database schema

Tags: database, database-schema

This should be a really simple question for any Oracle DBAs out there.

I just started on a new application and I asked to see the schema. I am not familiar with Oracle or its naming conventions at all. So I submit to you the following:

[image]

I'd like to know:

- Why the separation from the top 2 fields and the rest? (I assume those are PK but it doesnt explicitly state as much)
- What's the difference from the bolded fields and non-bolded?
- What does 'l3', 'l5', etc indicate?
- A couple other tables (not pictured) have 'U1' indicators where this pic has 'l3', what does that mean?

Comment: The questions have nothing to do with Oracle - only with whatever application you use to display the ER model.

Comment: Sorry, I have seen many db schemas and none have looked like this document, I assumed it was an oracle specific thing. You could have just removed the tag and updated the title, rather than posting a comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer you questions:

1. The top two fields indicate the primary keys for the table
2. Bolded fields are required ( NON-NULL ) fields
3. "I" indicates that the columns are indexed
4. "U" indicates that the columns have a unique key associated with them

Hope this helps.